# Image Max-width:100 what is the correct height?

Tags: css

I know this sounds obvious but I tried so many different options that I got totally confused now. I want my `img` to be maximum width 100% of their container and the proportionally correct height thereby.

So I am using

```css
.container {
  width:400px; //or something else
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.container img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

But that scales my imgs height not proportionally correct. What do I do wrong?

Comment: add one more rule `width:100%` to the img tag

Comment: `img {display: block; width: 100%}`

Answer (score 0):

Add 100% width to the img selector:

```
.container{
width:400px; //or something else
overflow-x:hidden;
}
.container img{
max-width:100%;
width: 100%;
height:auto;
}
```

You also don't need to set the height property value as it's initial value is auto